# PHP DOMXPath works with double quotes fails with single quotes

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I wrote a little script that extracts information from a web site using PHP's `DOMXPath` class.
I query for `<div class="sku" />` and execute a `substring-before` on the result. The result contains text, non breaking spaces, a line break and more text.
So what I'm trying to do is cut before the `&nbsp;&nbsp;\r\n`. It works fine when I use the following query:

```
$query = "substring-before(//div[@class='sku'],'\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\r\n')";
```

but fails as soon as I change the quotes (which shouldn't make any difference):

```
$query = 'substring-before(//div[@class="sku"],"\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\r\n")';
```

or

```
$query = 'substring-before(//div[@class=\'sku\'],\'\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\r\n\')';
```

**How is this possible and how can I overcome this?**

Live example here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/R1rCaj

Comment: You say "It works fine when I..." and then "how can I overcome this?" How about using the version that works fine? I guess your real question is "why does this behave differently?"

Comment: Are you saving PHP code into your database and you then `eval`uate it? Please complete your example, the actual code of xpath evaluation is not clear from your question. If you leave that out, it's not easy/possible to answer correctly.

Comment: @hakre: The expression `substring-before(//div[@class='sku'],'\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\r\n')` is indeed saved in a MySQL database and is loaded into a variable `$query` just like in my live example.

Comment: in your live example *nothing* is "loaded" into `$query1` (2,3). So either you ask about how to do some xpath query (which you don't actually have a problem with, so I guess not) -or- you ask about how you can keep a string *binary safe* when you fetch it from a database into a variable. For the later you have not provided any code. All code you give is about xpath, however I'm pretty sure that's not where the problem resides which you have. Please use `var_dump` on your string scenarios and give an exemplary table dump showing 1-3 rows with the xpath data. and show the db code (excerpt).

Comment: @hakre The xpath expression is stored in a `VARCHAR` in a MySQL database. I fetch it using PHP PDO and assign it to the variable `$query`. A `var_dump($query);` outputs `'substring-before(//div[@class=\'sku\'],\'\\xC2\\xA0\\xC2\\xA0\\r\\n\')'`. 
Afterall, you are right: My question is now how to keep a string binary safe when fetching it from a database storing it in a variable. I just did not expect this to be the problem at first - that's why I phrased the question like I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style of quotes makes a difference because [when a string is enclosed in double-quotes PHP will interpret more escape sequences for special characters](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) - including what you're using for non-breaking space `\xC2\xA0`, carriage return `\r`, and newline `\n`.

When you have these enclosed in single-quotes `'\xC2\xA0\r\n'`, like in your second two queries, PHP treats them as those literal characters - backslash, x, C, 2... etc.

---

A little extra syntax highlighting may help show this off, escape sequences in orange:

[image]

---

If your string already has what would be escape sequences in it as literal characters, and there's **no way** to get that corrected<sup>*</sup>, you're in the kinda dirty position of replacing them yourself.

This `preg_replace_callback()` will take care of the sort of sequences in your example, and it's trivial to extend to the rest of the escape sequences supported by double-quotes:

```
// Known good.
$query1 = "substring-before(//div[@class='sku'],'\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\r\n')";

// Known bad.
$query2 = 'substring-before(//div[@class=\'sku\'],\'\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\r\n\')';

$query2 = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\\\\(?:[rn]|(?:x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}))/',
    function ($matches) {
        switch (substr($matches[0], 0, 2)) {
            case '\r':
                return "\r";
            case '\n':
                return "\n";
            case '\x':
                return hex2bin(substr($matches[0], 2));
            }
    },
    $query2
);

var_dump($query1 === $query2); // Now equal?
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

---

<sub>*(*Really, you should get this fixed at the source.)*</sub>

Comment: Paul, that's a great answer and makes a lot of sense. In my case the xPath query comes from a database however and is saved into a PHP variable. How can I tell PHP not to use it as literal characters?

Comment: Thanks for the update. While your proposal might work for this specific example, I am looking for a general solution for this problem as the input is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easy with simple_html_dom
for download : http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/
Manual : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

```
    <?php
    // include simple html dom library
    include('./lib/simple_html_dom.php');
    $url="http://www.vosteen-shop.de/p-261232-edelstahl-herz-acero-zum-hngen-lnge-10cm-breite-10cm-silber-glanz.aspx";
    // get html in $html var
    $html=file_get_html($url);
    // find your class div.sku (plaintext) or you can get (innertext)
$results=$html->find('div.sku',0)->innertext;
$explode=explode("<b",$results);
$results=trim($explode[0]);
echo $results ;
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know there are several ways I can do this. However, I would like to stick with xPath and I was wondering  how this issue is possible.